# Views: Display only first value from content field in a staff directory

Tags: views, entities

I'm creating a staff directory for my library in Views. In one of the display field, Departments, staff often are assigned more than one departmental affiliation when I create their Content Profile. In this tabular view I'm creating, how can I make it so only the first value of the field representing departmental affiliation is displayed? It really clutters things up to display two or more departments in this table. I'd be happy to export the view & post it if that will help solve my problem.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Drupal 7 and Views 3. If that is true, then you could use the below -

Quoting from the comment here - http://drupal.org/node/1024158#comment-5064416

> Under fields, when you add your image field, one of the configuration options is "Multiple Field Settings". Under that make sure you check the box for "Display all values in the same row". The last line under this will ask how many items you want to display. Type "1". You can also specify which number to start with if you like. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great. If the solution worked for you 'as is', you could mark the answer as accepted, so this question does not appear in the unanswered list. Or you could edit the answer to add more steps in it that you might have had to follow. /me loves drupal.stackexchange :-)